# How to setup Microsoft LUIS to detect composed names (dash separated)

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I want to detect a person's name in LUIS, including a person with a composed name (eg: Mary-Anne)
Setup:

- a simple custom entity for names
- a pattern feature for dash separated words: **^\w*-\w*$**
- a feature Phrase List to try and get at least some examples working: **[marc-andre, marie-anne, jean-marc]**

I trained and published (on staging) and yet, it never detects the whole composed name, but instead will only return the first part as the entity (eg: entity is "marc" instead of "marc-andre").

Do you know how to configure LUIS to properly detect my composed name entity?

## Update taking Denise' answer into account

In the Luis.ai UI, i didn't realize that while labelling an utterance, it is possible to click more than once to select multiple words while specifying an entity.

[image: utterance labelling]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to configure a simple custom entity like you describe. I posted the JSON that you can import into LUIS [here](https://aka.ms/hyphen-names-json).

Without seeing the JSON for your LUIS app it's hard to tell why it fails to recognize the dash-separated names - feel free to post the JSON for your LUIS app here. Sometimes a LUIS app won't recognize an entity due to a lack of labeling. A key part of getting LUIS to recognize an entity is labeling enough examples. A pattern feature is just a hint to LUIS -- you still need to define example utterances that have the labeled entity. For example, if you have defined an intent called **MyNameIs** and want to recognize the **Name** entity within them, you'll want to add a variety of utterances to the **MyNameIs** intent that contain dash-separated names, and label each name with the entity.
[image]

When I added the pattern feature I used `+` to indicate "one or more" in the regex instead of `*`. However, this difference shouldn't break your pattern feature.
[image]

Another problem that can happen with hyphens is in the JSON that LUIS returns. When you inspect the JSON result from LUIS you can see how the Name entity is identified. Notice that in the `entity` field, LUIS inserts spaces around the hyphen, but the `startIndex` and `endIndex` fields identify the indexes of the entity in the original utterance. So if you have code that parses the `entity` field without using `startIndex` and `endIndex` on the `query` field the behavior might not be as you expect.

```
{
  "query": "my name is anne-marie",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "MyNameIs",
    "score": 0.9912877
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "anne - marie",
      "type": "Name",
      "startIndex": 11,
      "endIndex": 20,
      "score": 0.8978088
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Denise for this great answer.
I haven't tried yet to configure Luis using the API, it seems more powerfull than using the Luis.ai UI.  

What I didn't realize is that in the UI, you can keep clicking after the contextual menu shows up, to select multiple words for a single entity.  

Since then it seems to work very well. Thanks again.